# Ingress Nginx Proxy to Outside Website (Webflow hosted)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster, and a separate website built on (and hosted by) Webflow.

The cluster is behind `cluster.com` and the website `website.webflow.io`

What I would like to achieve is to proxy requests coming to `cluster.com/website` to `website.webflow.io`

Based on my research, this problem could/might be solved with the ExternalName service. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve it for me, and it's trying to do a DNS lookup within the cluster. I tried various other configurations with Endpoints as well. The ExternalName seems the most promising of everything I tried that's why I'm attaching the configuration below.

Here is what my configuration looks like:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  namespace: development
  name: external-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: website.webflow.io
  ports:
    - port: 443
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: development
  name: external-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-host: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "website.webflow.io"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_ssl_name website.webflow.io;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cluster.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /website
        backend:
          serviceName: external-service
          servicePort: 443
```

Is there a straight-forward way to achieve this? What stands out as wrong in the configuration?

Comment: "should/might work"? Have you even tried this? Do you expect me to test it for you?

Comment: Of course I tried it, as well as plenty of other approaches. This one was closest to what feels like should have worked, but it doesn't. It is trying to do a DNS lookup within the cluster itself.

Edit: By this should/might work I mean, ExternalName is the closest thing I found that could solve this problem. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I did.

I applied your config but changed the following annotation name:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "website.webflow.io"
```

To the one I have found in [the nginx ingress docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/):

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "website.webflow.io"
^^^^^^
```

Try it and let me know if it solves it.

EDIT:
here is a complete yaml I used:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: external-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: website.webflow.io
  ports:
    - port: 443

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: external-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-host: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "website.webflow.io"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_ssl_name website.webflow.io;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cluster.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /website
        backend:
          serviceName: external-service
          servicePort: 443
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, that didn't solve it. I keep getting 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable - I tried what you suggested as well as tweaking paths and annotations, but basically, I get the same error even with all the annotations disabled.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the reasoning behind the empty endpoint in this case?

Comment: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable (from nginx)

Comment: I dont get it, now it also works without endnpoint :(

Comment: Try copying and using the yaml I added to my asnwer

Comment: The full config you gave me works without the Endpoints object. Thank you good sir you are a gentleman and a scholar.